# How to check if the value of a field has been deleted in Python/ Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to check if a value of field has been deleted and then return `False` or `True` if all the fields contain values.

My code actually doesn't check the value in the fields but just checks if the fields exists.

How to check the values of every specific field?

This is my models and in my views I have to check the function.

```
# models.py
class CompanyDirector(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    directorTitle = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
    directorName = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    directorSurname = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    directorId = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)  
    proffessionStartDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

---

```
# views.py
ret = {'complete': False}
  try:
      company_director = 
 CompanyDirector.objects.filter(company__token=token).first()
      if company_director:
        ret['complete'] = True
        for field in company_director._meta.get_all_field_names():
          if not getattr(company_director, field):
            ret['complete'] = False
            break;
  except ValueError as e:
     print (e)
  return Response(ret)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `values` from the queryset, which will be a `dict` object.

**Solution**:

```
company_director = CompanyDirector.objects.filter(company__token=token).values().first()
if company_director:
    for field, value in company_director.items():
        if value is None:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Use `for value in company_director.values()` instead if you don't need the keys.